# Prevent Roomle Camera from resetting

Tags: roomle

As can be seen in the [example](https://hs97m.csb.app/) provided in the [tutorial](https://docs.roomle.com/web/guides/tutorial/configurator/) the Roomle configurator demonstrates different behaviors when zoomed in and a parameter is changed:

1. If the user clicks on the component and then scrolls to zoom in, the parameters of the component can be changed and the camera will stay in place.
2. If the user does not select the component first and just zooms in, the camera will reset to its original position if a parameter is changed.

I want to programmatically control camera movement and parameter selection without direct user interaction with the Roomle configurator (custom GUI) and this 2nd behavior is very annoying as the camera always jumps around.

I've tried using `RoomleConfigurator._sceneHelper._cameraControl.lock()` which successfully prevents manual camera movement but it will still reset on a parameter change.

How can I achieve the 1st behavior, where the camera is locked in place?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to deactivate this behaviour (camera reset on parameter change).

Also a word of warning regarding the code `RoomleConfigurator._sceneHelper._cameraControl.lock()`. Functions which start with an underscore (`_`) are private and may be subject to change in a future release.

Here you can find the documentation on how to move the camera using the official API:

https://docs.roomle.com/web/guides/tutorial/configurator/07_recipes.html#move-camera